# jQuery click event not firing for div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't understand why this isn't working. I have a table that includes a div and an image in the header. When I click on this, I want to fire the click event via a jQuery function. Here is a screenshot of the HTML:

[image]

And here is the jQuery function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('ready');

    $('#add_external_link').on('click',function(){
        alert('clicked');
    });
});
```

I believe that the element is in the DOM before the event is bound. The tail of the HTML looks like this (it's the 'external_link_dialog.js' file that contains the jQuery language from above):

```
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.dlmenu.js"></script>
        <script src="js/external_link_dialog.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

My console output shows `ready` as soon as the page is loaded. However, when I click that `<div>`, nothing happens. I see no errors, no console output, and of course no alert. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? I've been at this for hours, and am out of ideas. Thank you!

Comment: try event delegation... if the element is create dynamically - `$(document).on('click', '#add_external_link', function () {
    alert('clicked');
});`

Comment: also is there any error in your browser console

Comment: Are you adding this `div` dynamically?

Comment: Well for one it doesn't look like you're closing your on click function...

Comment: I think you haven't closed your click event properly!! Is that typo?

Comment: Are you reading console log? This should give syntax error.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.

Comment: @Randall did you try event delegation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess that you are appending the div after the document.ready . 
If you are adding that `add_external_link` div dynamically, you should attach the `.on("click` function **after** appending that **div**.

If the div is not added dynamically, then try adding a timeout

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('ready');
    setTimeout(function(){
      $(document).on('click','#add_external_link',function(){
          alert('clicked');
      });
   },1000);
});
```

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail this approach? I don't understand why event delegation wasn't enough so that you additionnaly set a timeout.

Comment: Thanks. This saved my whole day. Best way for me.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your CSS, the div may actually be smaller than the image you're trying to click on.

Try setting your target to the following:

```
$('#add_external_link img').on('click', function(){
    alert('clicked');
});
```

Comment: Taking CSS into accout is very important in this OP.  Randall, it is better to confirm that both image and div are fitting each others in surface and that they aren't very small. If  so, this answer is smart even with few probability

Comment: This is a really good suggestion. I've confirmed that my div is larger than the image, so it doesn't seem to be the issue here. It definitely helps me for future reference, however. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try  delegating to document or the closest static element.

```
$(document).on('click','#add_external_link',function(){
    alert('clicked');
});
```

Comment: I agree with the delegation, but delegate to document is not very efficient, I think. Delegate in your situation to the parent table or parent-table-div of the div-to-click. That makes rendering more easy.